# How to properly display JSON result in a table via ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have this code which fetches data from an API and displays JSON response in a div. How do I display the JSON response in a table?

This is how I display it in div via **status.jsx**:

```
// some codings
render() {
    const { status, isLocal } = this.props;

    if(!isLocal()) {
      return (



        <div className="status">
          <div className="status-text">
           <b>Status</b> {status.text}<br />
  <b>Title</b> status.textTitle} <br /> 
<b>Event</b> {status.textEvent}
          </div>
        </div>

      )
    }
}
```

I have tried displaying it in a table as per below but could not get it to be aligned properly

```
//some codings
render() {
    const { status, isLocal } = this.props;

    if(!isLocal()) {
      return (

<table>
      <tbody>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Event</th>
<tr>
             <td>{status.text} </td>
  <td>{status.textTitle} </td>
  <td>{status.textEvent}</td>
<td><button
            className="btn btn-danger status-delete"
            onClick={this.toggleDeleteConfirmation}
            disabled={this.state.showDeleteConfirmation}
          >
              Delete
          </button></td>
</tr></tbody>
       </table>


      )
    }
}
```

Here is **profile.jsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  isSignInPending,
  loadUserData,
  Person,
  getFile,
  putFile,
  lookupProfile
} from 'bs';
import Status from './Status.jsx';

const avatarFallbackImage = 'https://mysite/onename/avatar-placeholder.png';
const statusFileName = 'statuses.json';

export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      person: {
        name() {
          return 'Anonymous';
        },
        avatarUrl() {
          return avatarFallbackImage;
        },
      },
      username: "",
      statuses: [],
      statusIndex: 0,
      isLoading: false
    };

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.isLocal = this.isLocal.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }




  handleDelete(id) {
    const statuses = this.state.statuses.filter((status) => status.id !== id)
    const options = { encrypt: false }

    putFile(statusFileName, JSON.stringify(statuses), options)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          statuses
        })
      })
  }




  fetchData() {
    if (this.isLocal()) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true })
      const options = { decrypt: false, zoneFileLookupURL: 'https://myapi/v1/names/' }
      getFile(statusFileName, options)
        .then((file) => {
          var statuses = JSON.parse(file || '[]')
          this.setState({
            person: new Person(loadUserData().profile),
            username: loadUserData().username,
            statusIndex: statuses.length,
            statuses: statuses,
          })
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        })
    } else {
      const username = this.props.match.params.username
      this.setState({ isLoading: true })

      lookupProfile(username)
        .then((profile) => {
          this.setState({
            person: new Person(profile),
            username: username
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('could not resolve profile')
        })

      const options = { username: username, decrypt: false, zoneFileLookupURL: 'https://myapi/v1/names/'}

      getFile(statusFileName, options)
        .then((file) => {
          var statuses = JSON.parse(file || '[]')
          this.setState({
            statusIndex: statuses.length,
            statuses: statuses
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('could not fetch statuses')
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        })
    }
  }

  isLocal() {
    return this.props.match.params.username ? false : true
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSignOut } = this.props;
    const { person } = this.state;
    const { username } = this.state;

    return (
      !isSignInPending() && person ?
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            {this.isLocal() &&
              <div className="new-status">
               Hello

              </div>
            }
            <div className="col-md-12 statuses">
            {this.state.isLoading && <span>Loading...</span>}
            {
              this.state.statuses.map((status) => (
                <Status
                  key={status.id}
                  status={status}
                  handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                  isLocal={this.isLocal}
                />
              ))
            }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> : null
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your table is missing a `<tr>` to wrap the heading (`<th>` tags). You also have only 3 columns in the heading, but 4 columns in the body, which may be causing the lack of alignment.